# Virtual Host issue on a local environment using Fedora and apache

Tags: apache, permissions, local, virtualhost, fedora

Welcome. I read through a ton of posts with similar issues like mine but nothing helped in the end.

I´m trying to setup a virtual host for a website which im working on locally.

- My os is an up to date Fedora
- And Apache2 the web-server I use.

Next I added this line to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Include conf/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Now configuring /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf like so:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /home/pfl/sites/bonnielassie
 ServerName bonnie.lo
 <Directory /home/pfl/sites/bonnielassie>
  AllowOverride none
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>

 CustomLog /var/log/bonnie.lo combined
 ErrorLog /var/log/bonnie.lo.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Going on with editing /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 bonnie.lo
```

Permissions i set like this:

```
chown -R apache:apache /home/pfl
chmod -R 755 /home/pfl
chown -R /var/www
chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

If i check the log file /var/log/bonnie.lo.log it tells me:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/pfl/sites/bonnielassie/bonnie.lo
```

And if i try to open the site with a webbrowser it tells me:

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /bonnie.lo on this server.

If i run sestatus it gives back:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      30
```

Comment: SELinux? What are the permissions of that file?

Comment: I added the return of sestatus to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory "/home/pfl/sites/bonnielassie">

restorecon -Frv /home/pfl/sites

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.